# Move zeroes to the middle of the array?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am practicing Data Structures and Algorithms in Java. I came across the leetcode question move all zeroes to the end. I was able to solve it. Now for my own practice, I thought of changing the question a little bit, as to how to move all the existing zeroes in an array to the center of the array. I have been trying to solve it but have not been able to cover all the different types of inputs. I can move the zeroes when the numbers are shuffled but not when all the zeroes are at the start or the end of the array. I would really appreciate any help I can help with this.
My code **works** with the input: {1, 2, 0, 3, 12, 15, 0, 17, 18};
But **not** with the input: {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3};
Thanks.
My Code:

```
public static int[] moveZeroesToMiddle(int[] nums) {
    int indexS = 0;
    int indexE = nums.length - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length / 2; i++) {
        if(nums[i] != 0) nums[indexS++] = nums[i];
    }
    for(int i = nums.length - 1; i > nums.length / 2 - 1; i--) {
        if(nums[i] != 0) nums[indexE--] = nums[i];
    }
    for(int i = indexS; i <= indexE; i++) nums[i] = 0;
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Not exactly clear what is the problem - you seem to be able to move all zeros to the end. Adding code to move a block of non-zero values to the end in the array and fill the middle with zeros should not be a problem... Or you trying to do it in one pass by moving items to outer boundaries to keep length balanced?

Comment: If you are practicing JAVA then why used C# tag ?

Comment: What do you mean by moving to the middle? Is it like filling array[n/2] first followed by array[n/2 -1] , array[n/2 +1]?

Comment: Define _middle_ . Does it mean they just need to be surrounded with non-zero numbers?

Answer (score -1):

I hope the following works.

```
public static int[] moveZeroesToMiddle(int[] nums)
{
    int startpos = 0;
    int endpos = nums.length-1;  
    int[] res = new int[nums.length];
    
    boolean isStart = true; //this determines whether the number moves to start or end
    
    for(int cursor = 0;cursor<= nums.length-1; cursor++)
    {
        if(nums[cursor] == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        int pos;
            
        if(isStart)
        {
            pos = startpos++;
            isStart = false;
        }
        else
        {
            pos = endpos--;
            isStart = true;
        }
            
        res[pos] = nums[cursor];
        
    }
    
    for(int cursor = startpos; cursor <= endpos ; cursor++)
    {
        res[cursor] = 0;
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void MoveZeroesToCenter(int[] nums)
{
    int numsOfZero = 0;
    for (int i = 0, lastNonZeroIndex = 0; i < nums.Length;  i++)
    {
        if(nums[i] != 0)
        {
            swap(lastNonZeroIndex, i, nums);
      
            lastNonZeroIndex++;
        }
        else
        numsOfZero++;

    }
    var mid = Math.Abs(nums.Length / 2);

    var zeroStartIndex = mid - Math.Abs(numsOfZero / 2);
    for(int i = zeroStartIndex; i + numsOfZero < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        swap(i, i + numsOfZero, nums);
    }
}

public static void swap(int a, int b, int[] nums)
{
    int temp = nums[b];
    nums[b] = nums[a];
    nums[a] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Explain your code. Posting only the code in not helpful at all.